# How to extend Ubuntu disk space without using Live CD?

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk

I first installed Windows 7 from factory, then installed Ubuntu.

I ran out of space, but there is a lot in Windows partition. So I wanted to allocate some space from the Windows partition to Ubuntu partition with gparted. I burnt the live CD but can't reboot from CD ROM.

I tried to choose it from the BIOS menu (by pressing F12) and also tried changing the boot order (no floppy).

Is there a way to extend the Ubuntu partition without using Ubuntu Live CDROM?

Comment: how did you install ubuntu?? is it via the windows installer or via live cd??

Answer (score 4):

use easus partition master (or any other that you prefer) on windows to resize the partition of ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

if you have a flash drive then you can create **USB Startup disk** and then boot Ubuntu using that flash drive. From there you can run gparted or any thing else that you want. Also as you booted Ubuntu from Flash and not from harddisk, you can easily edit any of your partitions

Answer (score 0):

Use `tuxboot` or `unetbootin` to create a bootable usb of gparted live. just use any Ubuntu  live CD installer and boot into it  and select "Try Ubuntu" option.

Now use *gparted partition editor* to extend the Ubuntu partition on your system,the thing is that for any operation like extending, creating, moving etc, have to be performed when the volume is offline i.e The volume or partition can't be mounted, so when you're using Ubuntu on your system its not possible to do this because your system partition is mounted in `/`.

And Easeus partition manager would not do any fancy operation on Ubuntu partitions (such as ext3,ext4).

Comment: Actually Easeus partition manager support operations on ext2, ext3. Though, I am not very sure about ext4